# TFS SCC: How can I get new files listed in the Pending Changes Panel in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tortoisesvn

We are experimenting to use Microsoft Team Foundation Server Source Code Control as a replacement for SVN.

Therefore, it would be great if the friction for this transition would be minimal.

For example, in SVN, whenever I create new files in the folder, and then use "Tortoise SVN Check for Modifications", I get a master list of Added Files, Deleted Files, and Edited Files.

I know that in TFS SCC in Visual Studio, the equivalent is the Pending Changes Panel. However, this panel only lists Edited Files. How can I get new files listed in that panel, too, just like SVN does?

Comment: It should show files that have *any* pending change, be it edit, add, delete or even branch, merge, etc.  Could you describe your workflow a bit more?

Comment: @Edward: In SVN, it lists the files that are candidates for Adding.   

In TFS, it doesn't do this. So I have to manually keep track of the files I added, it's too much meta-work. I'm coming from an SVN workflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workflow really depends on whether you are using `Local Workspaces` or the traditional `Server Workspaces`.  As you are coming from SVN, `Local Workspaces` would probably be a good fit.

**Local Workspaces (New to TFS 2012)**

`Local Workspaces` are TFS's attempt at DVCS and actually gives you a much more SVN-Like experience.  The `pending changes` window with local workspaces is divided up into the following areas:

- `Included Changes` - This is effectively files that are **already** in Source Control that have been changed.
- `Excluded Changes` - These are all files within the workspace that are not in source control.  This is like your `Added` files in SVN.

**Server Workspaces**

`Server Workspaces` are the traditional TFS workspace approach.  An item is not **in** Source Control until it is explicitly added.

There is a much more detailed article on the differences here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb892960.aspx

Comment: I'm to slow, but what should be added is, that the `Local Workspaces` are a new feature of `TFS2012`

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop your new files into the right folders in the `Source Control Explorer` in Visual studio and then there will be asked if there are also files that need to be excluded from the source control. If that is done they are in the `Pending changes window`. The implementation like SVN is starting from Visual studio 2012 but then still it can give issues and not be in that panel.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question but I believe the answer is in Visual Studio's "**Pending Changes Panel**" itself. Notice the "**Excluded Changes (nnn)**" section. Just below that heading you should find "**Detected: nnn add(s)**". You can see your 'new files' listed there.

For what it's worth, I find the "Pending Changes" an unwieldy feature in that it seems it's never context aware. I find that I often have to "weed through" many, many files that are simply not relevant to the solution/project(s) at hand.